Finding an explicit expression for the recurrence relation.
The following is a contest problem intended for high schoolers. It seems to be a contest called IJMO:
Consider the sequence of real numbers $a_n$ for $n=1, 2, 3, ...,$
$$a_1=2 \;\text{and} \;a_n={n+1\over n-1}(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i) \; \text{for all}\;n\ge2$$
Determine the value of:
$$\frac{a_{2017}}{2^{2017}}$$
$$$$
After observing the terms in the given sequence, I conjectured that the sequence has the explicit expression $a_n=2^{n-1}(n+1)$ and I can prove that this is true by proof by induction. Thus, the answer to my own question would be 1009 by calculation.
However, I was rather lucky to find a certain pattern to the sequence and was able to form a conjecture for the induction proof to take place. I wonder if there is a way to actually obtain the explicit expression directly.
Thank you in advance, if you did attempt my problem here.

I already did that, I was just wondering if there's a way to get the expression explicitly without induction, which was already answered.

$$\begin{align}
&a_n = \frac{n+1}{n-1}\left(a_{n-1}+\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}a_i}_{=\frac{n-2}{n}\cdot a_{n-1}}\right) = \frac{n+1}{n-1}\cdot \left(a_{n-1} + \frac{n-2}{n}\cdot a_{n-1}  \right) = 2\cdot\frac{n+1}{n}\cdot a_{n-1}\\
\implies &\frac{a_n}{n+1} = 2\cdot \frac{a_{n-1}}{n}=... = 2^{n-1}\cdot  \frac{a_1}{2}\\
\implies &a_n =2^{n-2}\cdot (n+1)
\end{align}$$

Looked like there's a slight typo at the end, but this definitely answered my question, thank you!
